# How to handle two generic objects in Type Script function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a two generic types:

```
type Organization {
 id: String
 name: String
 type: String
}

type OrganizaationInput {
 id: String
 name: String
}
```

As you see difference is only one parameter (type). Both of this types were generated by codegen and I CAN'T change them.
Also I have a function which can take this kind of objects as input parameters.

```
getCustomerFromOrganization(organization: Organization): Customers{
    ....
}
```

And my problem appears when I try to call this function with type OrganizationInput.
How can I call the function getCustomerFromOrganization with both types?

p.s (organization: Organization | OrganizationInput) doesn't help

Comment: Just write another function with argument type `OrganizaationInput`

Comment: I don't like copy paste. It is one function...

Comment: There are no [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in this question or its answer; could you untag it and remove the word "generic"?  Also, please consider providing a [mre] which clearly demonstrates the problem you're having. You say "when I try to call this function"... could you show us?  You say "`Organization | OrganizationInput` doesn't help"... again, could you show us that?

Comment: Your code gen tool is using `String` instead of `string`?  [That's not recommended](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object).  Since you can't change it, I guess there's unfortunately nothing you can do about it (or the misspelled `Organizaation`), but maybe you can find someone who can do something about it and tell them.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Answer if found -

```
if ("type" in organization) {
    const { type } = organization;
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how this answers the question, since as written it doesn't compile.  Could you provide enough code so that it could be dropped into an IDE and someone could see for themselves that it works?  And/or provide a link to a TS Playground or other web IDE which shows it?

Comment: Sure - 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gTgcwIYDsCWAvJw0HsVQC8UA3gFBSVRoAmAXFAMrBxooIVUpIC2EDzVu06VQkASzYcAvmTJjo8ZOizY8KAJIowAV2BFSI6vSaThVKNz4ShMuQDMdKAMY58UBBGABhHQGdgXD44ADE4IKVUTDV8AApcRCisNxQGSJUkGM1tPQBKBgA3XFoyRxcUjy9fAKCIUPCedOiU+MSMirS25vUoAB9YLtUUrV1gfKgi2nILNHtYgHIFeeoCBOVu-FzDCwtnfADSKAUoaQM1pKyAbiNd-dwAGwgAOnvcBFiFXOuLWWkgA

Comment: The code should be edited directly into the plaintext of the answer also (and not just as a link in the comments), since it depends on `organization` being of type `Organization | OrganizaationInput`, which is not mentioned.  Also: do you want [this](https://tsplay.dev/WK7DzW) to happen?  If not, why do you have the overload signature?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
type Organization = {
    id: String
    name: String
    type: String
}

type OrganizaationInput = {
    id: String
    name: String
}

function getCustomerFromOrganization(organization: OrganizaationInput): void
function getCustomerFromOrganization(organization : Organization | OrganizaationInput): void{
   if ("type" in organization) {
        const { type } = organization;
    }
}
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gTgcwIYDsCWAvJw0HsVQC8UA3gFBSVRoAmAXFAMrBxooIVUpIC2EDzVu06VQkASzYcAvmTJjo8ZOizY8KAJIowAV2BFSI6vSaThVKNz4ShMuQDMdKAMY58UBBGABhHQGdgXD44ADE4IKVUTDV8AApcRCisNxQGSJUkGM1tPQBKBgA3XFoyRxcUjy9fAKCIUPCedOiU%20MSMirS25vUoAB9YLtUUrV1gfKgi2nILADo5smkgA)

Inside the function you need to check actual type. The simple option is to use code from example.

However I would suggest [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

```
type Organization = {
    id: String
    name: String
    type: String
}


function isOrganization(input: Organization | OrganizaationInput): input is Organization {
    return "type" in input;
}
```

Comment: Try to use type variable in second function. It doesn't let you...

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gTgcwIYDsCWAvJw0HsVQC8UA3gFBSVRoAmAXFAMrBxooIVUpIC2EDzVu06VQkASzYcAvmTJjo8ZOizY8KAJIowAV2BFSI6vSaThVKNz4ShMuQDMdKAMY58UBBGABhHQGdgXD44ADE4IKVUTDV8AApcRCisNxQGSJUkGM1tPQBKBgA3XFoyRxcUjy9fAKCIUPCedOiU+MSMirS25vUoAB9YLtUUrV1gfKgi2nILZ3wA0igFKGkDBOVu-ABuMmkgA

Comment: @NikitaPolevoy check the update